# Where to ask when it mostly concerns Visual Studio installation

Tags: discussion

I don't think the main Stack Overflow site is the correct place to ask.

I had a very specific problem after installing one of the Visual Studio components.

My question would be about a Visual Studio **installation issue.**

Is there a place in the Stack Overflow community to ask these kind of questions?

(This is probably a duplicate, but since i couldn't find anything related...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is a tool that developers use, and from my understanding, that'd be an alright question to pose *after* you've exhausted Google or other reference material.

Do yourself a favor:  when asking this question, be **specific** and **clear** about how you're installing Visual Studio (OS version, VS version, etc), and be explicit about the error message you're getting.

Comment: Ok, i wasn't very specific HERE because it's a meta question, but if i ask on main SO, i will be extremely specific and show effort of my research. All's good then.