# Is this highly upvoted installation question salvageable?

Tags: discussion

This question: [cygwin 2.5.2 mirror -- getting the last XP release](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39479826/1166898) was closed for asking for a resource, however, it's actually asking how to install Cygwin on Windows XP. I found it incredibly useful as I had exactly the same problem which I was able to resolve due to this question and its answers.

Admittedly, it does start with a rant that could be removed. If it was cleaned up and edited, would it be on-topic and reopened? If not on SO, would it be on-topic elsewhere on SE?

Comment: You see the answer with all the crossed out links in it and updates? _That’s_ why it’s closed, and that’s why it shouldn’t be reopened. What if the answerer gets bored updating the links when they change, and no one else is curating it? It becomes useless. That’s why questions that are fundamentally “find me a link”, regardless of what the link is needed for, should stay closed

Comment: You are likely to considerably speed up its demise by focusing meta attention on that Q+A.  I'd have to recommend you delete your meta question ;)

Comment: I thought it was useful as it stands. Do you think it would be substantially "better" if it were still open? (It does have three reopen votes.)

Comment: I think the biggest reason the linked question should be closed/deleted is that it is not a programming question.

Comment: @rmaddy not directly, but cygwin is a tool commonly used to aid development.

Comment: @Gimby Yeah but the question is only about installation, not using the tool for programming.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, [on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359507/424903) because its a development tool.

Comment: @Gimby Just because a piece of software may be used in conjunction with software development doesn't mean that a basic question about installing that piece of software is an on-topic programming question. A question about using the software in the act of programming would be on-topic. A non-programming question about installing a piece of software that may be used in a future task of programming is not on-topic. It's no different than asking about how much RAM I should install in my computer. Clearly off-topic despite the fact that I use my computer for programming.